# App crashes on slow connection

Tags: android, xml, android-fragments

I have implemented ActionBar TabListener with 3 tabs.
Every tab has three similar fragments which contains listview which are populated from same XML file.

My problem is that my XML file is being downladed every time when I swipe between tabs, and on slow connection my app is trying to download XML file on every swipe between tabs and after while it crashes. When there is no internet connection everything works fine, and my fragments are using last known Adapter to show ListView in every fragment.

My download procedure:

```
if(isNetworkAvailable() ){
    Log.i("mobAppModel", "starting download Task");
    AppDownloadTask download = new AppDownloadTask();
    download.execute();
}else {
    mAdapter = new AppAdapter(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), -1, XMLsourcePullParser.getmobAppModel(getActivity()));
    siteList.setAdapter(mAdapter);
}

return rootView;
```

AppDownloadTask:

```
private class AppDownloadTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>{
    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... arg0) {
        //Download the file

           try {                
            Downloader.DownloadFromUrl("http://URL_on_XML_file/", getActivity().openFileOutput("XMLsource.xml", Context.MODE_PRIVATE));
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return null;
    }
```

How can I bypass downloading XML file every time, or if there is slow connection to use last known Adapter?

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like your problem is that before the xml file is downloaded, you have uninitialized variables.  If it works when you have no network connection, I'd create a flag mXmlDownloaded.  Default it to false.  When the xml file is downloaded, set it to true.  Everywhere you change the code as follows:

```
if(isNetworkAvailable() ){
    Log.i("mobAppModel", "starting download Task");
    AppDownloadTask download = new AppDownloadTask();
    download.execute();
}else {
    if(mXmlDownloaded){
        mAdapter = new AppAdapter(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), -1, XMLsourcePullParser.getmobAppModel(getActivity()));
        siteList.setAdapter(mAdapter);
    }
}
```

Change any other place you use those variables similarly.  This way you won't use them until you have the data.